# Not able to add node to a cluster in Cassandra upgrading from 2.1.0 to 2.1.7

Tags: cassandra, upgrade, datastax

I was upgrading cassandra on my production server from 2.1.0 to 2.1.7 (latest stable version). I have made a parallel cluster for this, for testing before moving production to datastax cassandra 2.1.7 binary. I have created two server with 2.1.7 binary and copied my production data on both the server. When I start node one then everything seems fine but on starting the other node i am getting error. "error: No nodes present in the cluster. Has this node finished starting up?".
on running nodetool status I ca see only one node and get the below error.

> nodetool status error: No nodes present in the cluster. Has this node
>   finished starting up?
>   -- StackTrace -- java.lang.RuntimeException: No nodes present in the cluster. Has this node finished starting up?
>           at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner.describeOwnership(RandomPartitioner.java:143)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.getOwnership(StorageService.java:3900)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.getAttribute(PerInterface.java:83)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.getAttribute(MBeanSupport.java:206)
>           at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:647)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678)
>           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1464)
>           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
>           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
>           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
>           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getAttribute(RMIConnectionImpl.java:657)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Please suggest the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Please paste your output.log

Comment: This nodetool stacktrace happens when the node is still coming up, it usually takes some time to read the sstables and start gossip binary and thrift.